# Multiple strings Base64-decoded to same byte-array

Tags: security, http, encryption, base64

I have a byte-array (let's call it Encrypted Message), which I'm Base64-encoding to get an output string (let's call it token). At a later time, I'm Base64-decoding this token, to recover the original Encrypted Message.

For testing purposes, I've tried injecting one random bit flip in the token, to verify that the encryption/authentication does indeed fail when a random bit is flipped. 99% of the time, this is indeed the case. 1-3% of the time, this doesn't occur. I've debugged this back to the following behavior: 2 different tokens, both result in the same byte-array when Base64 decoded.

[I can understand if this happens for the last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941270/why-do-base64-decode-produce-same-byte-array-for-different-strings), but in my case, the 2 tokens actually differ in the middle.

The frequency at which this happens is also very puzzling. Given that there are ~1kB in the byte-buffer, even if 1-2 bytes are used only for padding and are meaningless, the odds of a random bit flip hitting the padding byte should be ~0.1%. I'm seeing this behavior happen >1% of the time.

Is this behavior reasonable? Or is there some deeper problem in my code?

**Question Summary**: Is it possible for 2 different strings, that differ by 1 bit flip in the middle, to produce the same byte array when Base64 decoded? For a 1kB buffer with 1 random bit flip, is it reasonable for this to occur 1% of the time?

**Full details**

I'm using Java's BASE64 encoder/decoder classes to do all operations below.

```
String token = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encryptedMessage);
...
byte[] tokenBytes = token.getBytes();
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(tokenBytes.length);
int randomBit = 1 << new Random().nextInt(8);
tokenBytes[randomIndex] ^= randomBit;
token = new String(tokenBytes)
....
byte[] finalEncryptedMessage = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(token);
checkFinalEncryptedMessage!=initialEncryptedMessage
```

Original encrypted message (byte array):

```
[52, -11, 14, -3, 10, 92, 65, -46, -54, -25, 117, -126, 15, 2, -72, 123, -119, 111, -115, 114, -11, 48, -6, 47, 72, -47, 117, 76, -17, 82, 98, 23, 124, -99, 92, -45, 92, 48, -116, 20, -90, 52, 94, -25, -116, 7, 112, -51, 20, -2, -66, 126, 11, 117, 81, 33, 27, -116, -46, -115, -64, -7, -83, 78, -113, 85, -106, -70, 46, 35, 42, -51, 118, -40, 40, 99, -29, -78, -117, -34, -65, -49, -18, -98, -84, 79, -115, -42, 93, 55, -115, -71, 6, 8, 106, -11, -5, 12, 11, -61, -9, -31, -114, 112, -119, 31, 37, 125, -9, 82, -53, 90, -43, 77, -53, -114, 118, 9, -68, 93, -48, 116, -116, 54, -82, 6, -52, 64, -66, 54, -34, 51, -3, -83, 49, -79, 81, -88, -122, -113, 6, -102, -11, 60, -128, 12, -105, -66, 4, -80, -2, -106, -73, 117, 55, -14, 96, 96, 107, -41, 16, 10, -83, -60, -88, -25, 49, -30, 19, 48, -85, -65, -70, -90, 0, -43, 100, 7, -106, 77, 70, -8, -87, 16, 108, 49, 102, -91, 41, -31, -45, 101, 61, -11, 108, -23, -117, 16, 52, -30, -46, -106, 78, 114, 64, -31, -82, 40, -109, 97, 61, -54, 50, -70, -106, -82, -21, -14, 78, -93, 101, -68, 107, 22, 18, 115, 3, 125, 44, -106, 126, -109, 8, -90, -81, 118, -34, 98, -111, -73, -67, -39, -51, -85, -104, 41, -37, 31, -29, 26, -114, -88, -116, -89, 27, -36, 74, -99, 101, -13, 76, 126, 1, -32, 59, 80, -102, -93, -92, 30, -49, -87, -28, -70, 88, 16, 117, 37, -49, 56, -6, 106, -74, -60, -71, -72, -91, -81, -9, -122, 53, -126, 28, -16, -126, -14, -24, -89, 19, -17, 20, 110, -25, 73, -74, 67, -65, 78, 103, 107, 116, -63, 84, -113, -114, -114, 24, 66, -6, -74, -71, 126, -112, 68, -37, 117, -88, 92, -13, 39, 18, -44, 92, 97, -84, -111, -118, -13, -73, -60, 69, -43, 74, 38, -89, 82, 74, 33, -41, 73, 87, 12, -114, 0, -48, 80, 1, -79, -53, -19, -4, 60, -8, 108, -85, -54, 104, 36, 77, -6, 30, 78, -104, 120, 33, 85, -87, -86, -57, -102, 97, -111, 43, 29, -63, 103, 101, 57, 64, 124, 53, -43, 118, 103, 107, 77, -97, 81, 90, 90, -102, 28, -57, 26, 18, -26, -21, 92, 36, -83, 22, 57, -33, 112, 1, -46, -23, -51, 121, 68, 45, -89, -25, -42, 103, 30, -113, -120, 36, 0, 19, 60, -28, 15, -63, -8, 97, -117, -69, -86, -55, -114, -89, -78, -5, -60, 86, 41, 117, -85, -38, -106, 2, -126, -107, 89, -93, -72, 20, 11, 48, 117, -57, -52, -9, 29, 54, -28, -13, 95, -100, 62, 107, -126, -22, -110, 40, -14, -110, 22, -10, -107, -87, -8, 45, -117, -3, -59, 22, 68, 92, 97, 48, -47, 90, 72, -13, 116, 50, 86, -44, -106, 95, -30, -89, 6, -69, 77, -64, 98, -110, 40, -59, -60, 58, 58, -11, -83, 81, -59, 65, 56, 105, 94, -2, 110, 73, 125, 46, 42, -52, 68, -28, 25, 97, -111, -98, -51, -50, 43, -31, -92, -88, 99, 26, -81, -62, 104, -117, -87, 70, -75, 26, -68, 18, -35, -4, 92, 79, -63, -24, 42, 34, 96, 63, -78, 58, -52, -71, 79, -121, 81, 65, 69, -24, -23, 55, -49, 10, 11, 33, -2, -8, 105, -95, -15, 6, 66, -121, 13, -124, -21, -103, -30, -56, -72, -44, 61, -67, -24, 96, -81, 20, -38, -21, -93, -35, 25, -105, -116, -15, -3, 71, 77, 0, -108, 85, 63, -114, 82, 31, -28, -61, -116, 74, 9, -1, -88, 67, 92, 14, 1, -90, -55, 105, -31, 5, -91, 123, 105, 2, -44, 71, 31, 8, 6, -68, 5, -35, 66, 112, 120, -38, 48, 85, 67, 89, -103, -43, 29, 120, 16, -4, 53, 72, -36, -56, 9, 42, -32, -98, -24, 66, 70, 54, -112, 73, -59, -124, 4, -51, 84, -120, 1, -18, -70, 66, -85, 27, 127, -85, -19, 117, -91, -63, 94, -46, 97, -35, -105, -84, -81, -118, -81, 107, 63, 65, -109, -36, -49, 111, -8, 77, 57, -91, -49, 2, 93, 103, 71, 48, 38, 28, 102, 9, -13, 25, 121, 95, -75, 69, -74, -18, -112, -122, -59, 17, -26, 81, 123, 54, 56, -127, -92, 32, 12, 86, 103, -84, 39, -18, 78, 100, 62, -78, -56, 84, -65, 80, -78, 102, -9, -48, 73, -98, 118, 74, 116, 39, -103, -127, 33, 48, -6, -48, 10, -69, -11, 118, -51, 1, -56, -59, -48, 103, -105, -109, -29, -100, 77, 66, 4, -85, -93, 46, -64, 61, -57, -111, -29, 89, -25, 126, -89, 65, -32, 33, -65, -70, 36, -19, -18, -79, 88, -79, 20, -91, -71, 13, -114, -44, 68, -14, -48, 106, -46, 105, 126, -6, -72, 113, -117, -46, 9, 27, -55, 113, 19, -69, -15, 36, -117, -90, 35, 122, 64, -108, -56]
```

Original token (after Base64 encode of above):

```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=
```

Corrupted token (see bit flip on 7th line. / replaced with ?)

```
NPUO/QpcQdLK53WCDwK4e4lvjXL1MPovSNF1TO9SYhd8nVzTXDCMFKY0XueMB3DNFP6+fgt1USEb
jNKNwPmtTo9VlrouIyrNdtgoY+Oyi96/z+6erE+N1l03jbkGCGr1+wwLw/fhjnCJHyV991LLWtVN
y452Cbxd0HSMNq4GzEC+Nt4z/a0xsVGoho8GmvU8gAyXvgSw/pa3dTfyYGBr1xAKrcSo5zHiEzCr
v7qmANVkB5ZNRvipEGwxZqUp4dNlPfVs6YsQNOLSlk5yQOGuKJNhPcoyupau6/JOo2W8axYScwN9
LJZ+kwimr3beYpG3vdnNq5gp2x/jGo6ojKcb3EqdZfNMfgHgO1Cao6Qez6nkulgQdSXPOPpqtsS5
uKWv94Y1ghzwgvLopxPvFG7nSbZDv05na3TBVI+OjhhC+ra5fpBE23WoXPMnEtRcYayRivO3xEXV
SianUkoh10lXDI4A0FABscvt?Dz4bKvKaCRN+h5OmHghVamqx5phkSsdwWdlOUB8NdV2Z2tNn1Fa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=
```

Final encrypted message, after Base64 decoding the above:

```
[52, -11, 14, -3, 10, 92, 65, -46, -54, -25, 117, -126, 15, 2, -72, 123, -119, 111, -115, 114, -11, 48, -6, 47, 72, -47, 117, 76, -17, 82, 98, 23, 124, -99, 92, -45, 92, 48, -116, 20, -90, 52, 94, -25, -116, 7, 112, -51, 20, -2, -66, 126, 11, 117, 81, 33, 27, -116, -46, -115, -64, -7, -83, 78, -113, 85, -106, -70, 46, 35, 42, -51, 118, -40, 40, 99, -29, -78, -117, -34, -65, -49, -18, -98, -84, 79, -115, -42, 93, 55, -115, -71, 6, 8, 106, -11, -5, 12, 11, -61, -9, -31, -114, 112, -119, 31, 37, 125, -9, 82, -53, 90, -43, 77, -53, -114, 118, 9, -68, 93, -48, 116, -116, 54, -82, 6, -52, 64, -66, 54, -34, 51, -3, -83, 49, -79, 81, -88, -122, -113, 6, -102, -11, 60, -128, 12, -105, -66, 4, -80, -2, -106, -73, 117, 55, -14, 96, 96, 107, -41, 16, 10, -83, -60, -88, -25, 49, -30, 19, 48, -85, -65, -70, -90, 0, -43, 100, 7, -106, 77, 70, -8, -87, 16, 108, 49, 102, -91, 41, -31, -45, 101, 61, -11, 108, -23, -117, 16, 52, -30, -46, -106, 78, 114, 64, -31, -82, 40, -109, 97, 61, -54, 50, -70, -106, -82, -21, -14, 78, -93, 101, -68, 107, 22, 18, 115, 3, 125, 44, -106, 126, -109, 8, -90, -81, 118, -34, 98, -111, -73, -67, -39, -51, -85, -104, 41, -37, 31, -29, 26, -114, -88, -116, -89, 27, -36, 74, -99, 101, -13, 76, 126, 1, -32, 59, 80, -102, -93, -92, 30, -49, -87, -28, -70, 88, 16, 117, 37, -49, 56, -6, 106, -74, -60, -71, -72, -91, -81, -9, -122, 53, -126, 28, -16, -126, -14, -24, -89, 19, -17, 20, 110, -25, 73, -74, 67, -65, 78, 103, 107, 116, -63, 84, -113, -114, -114, 24, 66, -6, -74, -71, 126, -112, 68, -37, 117, -88, 92, -13, 39, 18, -44, 92, 97, -84, -111, -118, -13, -73, -60, 69, -43, 74, 38, -89, 82, 74, 33, -41, 73, 87, 12, -114, 0, -48, 80, 1, -79, -53, -19, -4, 60, -8, 108, -85, -54, 104, 36, 77, -6, 30, 78, -104, 120, 33, 85, -87, -86, -57, -102, 97, -111, 43, 29, -63, 103, 101, 57, 64, 124, 53, -43, 118, 103, 107, 77, -97, 81, 90, 90, -102, 28, -57, 26, 18, -26, -21, 92, 36, -83, 22, 57, -33, 112, 1, -46, -23, -51, 121, 68, 45, -89, -25, -42, 103, 30, -113, -120, 36, 0, 19, 60, -28, 15, -63, -8, 97, -117, -69, -86, -55, -114, -89, -78, -5, -60, 86, 41, 117, -85, -38, -106, 2, -126, -107, 89, -93, -72, 20, 11, 48, 117, -57, -52, -9, 29, 54, -28, -13, 95, -100, 62, 107, -126, -22, -110, 40, -14, -110, 22, -10, -107, -87, -8, 45, -117, -3, -59, 22, 68, 92, 97, 48, -47, 90, 72, -13, 116, 50, 86, -44, -106, 95, -30, -89, 6, -69, 77, -64, 98, -110, 40, -59, -60, 58, 58, -11, -83, 81, -59, 65, 56, 105, 94, -2, 110, 73, 125, 46, 42, -52, 68, -28, 25, 97, -111, -98, -51, -50, 43, -31, -92, -88, 99, 26, -81, -62, 104, -117, -87, 70, -75, 26, -68, 18, -35, -4, 92, 79, -63, -24, 42, 34, 96, 63, -78, 58, -52, -71, 79, -121, 81, 65, 69, -24, -23, 55, -49, 10, 11, 33, -2, -8, 105, -95, -15, 6, 66, -121, 13, -124, -21, -103, -30, -56, -72, -44, 61, -67, -24, 96, -81, 20, -38, -21, -93, -35, 25, -105, -116, -15, -3, 71, 77, 0, -108, 85, 63, -114, 82, 31, -28, -61, -116, 74, 9, -1, -88, 67, 92, 14, 1, -90, -55, 105, -31, 5, -91, 123, 105, 2, -44, 71, 31, 8, 6, -68, 5, -35, 66, 112, 120, -38, 48, 85, 67, 89, -103, -43, 29, 120, 16, -4, 53, 72, -36, -56, 9, 42, -32, -98, -24, 66, 70, 54, -112, 73, -59, -124, 4, -51, 84, -120, 1, -18, -70, 66, -85, 27, 127, -85, -19, 117, -91, -63, 94, -46, 97, -35, -105, -84, -81, -118, -81, 107, 63, 65, -109, -36, -49, 111, -8, 77, 57, -91, -49, 2, 93, 103, 71, 48, 38, 28, 102, 9, -13, 25, 121, 95, -75, 69, -74, -18, -112, -122, -59, 17, -26, 81, 123, 54, 56, -127, -92, 32, 12, 86, 103, -84, 39, -18, 78, 100, 62, -78, -56, 84, -65, 80, -78, 102, -9, -48, 73, -98, 118, 74, 116, 39, -103, -127, 33, 48, -6, -48, 10, -69, -11, 118, -51, 1, -56, -59, -48, 103, -105, -109, -29, -100, 77, 66, 4, -85, -93, 46, -64, 61, -57, -111, -29, 89, -25, 126, -89, 65, -32, 33, -65, -70, 36, -19, -18, -79, 88, -79, 20, -91, -71, 13, -114, -44, 68, -14, -48, 106, -46, 105, 126, -6, -72, 113, -117, -46, 9, 27, -55, 113, 19, -69, -15, 36, -117, -90, 35, 122, 64, -108, -56]
```

Comment: What authentication do you have? What exactly do you expect to happen? What exactly happens when encryption "fails"?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thanks for taking a look. I'd like to avoid getting sidetracked into a discussion about encryption, because that's not what my question is about. It's purely about Base64 encoding/decoding. If I had to summarize my question in 1 line: *Is it possible for 2 different strings, that differ by 1 bit flip in the middle, to produce the same byte array when Base64 decoded? For a 1kB buffer with 1 random bit flip, is it reasonable for this to occur 1% of the time?*

Comment: base64 encoding is one-to-one. Changing any character is guaranteed to produce a different byte array upon decoding.

Comment: Do you have any explanation for the behavior I'm seeing above? I've added in the code that I'm using as well

Comment: You have changed that character to an invalid base64 character. Therefore the result will be decoder specific. However, I would expect most decoders to either throw an exception or ignore the character. Either way, you would not end up with the same result. I am not aware of the particular  base64 class you are using.

Comment: Oh, *that* BaseDecoder class. This is no doubt sun.misc.Base64Decoder. Those are internal classes and should not be used. They are undocumented, in particular their error behavior is undocumented. java.util.Base64 is a better choice for Java 8.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying that. Interestingly, I switched to using DatatypeConverter, and am still seeing the same behavior. The full solution would be for me to not use invalid Base64 characters like you mentioned. 

Why didn't you post your comment as an answer? Since you did post what was effectively the answer 2 hours before SlashingWeapon, I'd be happy to accept yours as the official answer, if you'd like to post a answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed that character to an invalid base64 character. Therefore the result will be decoder specific.

Your testing has revealed that some base64 decoders deal with invalid base64 characters better than others. The best solution is to use a Base64 decoder with a documented error behavior that matches your expectations. There are two now in Java 8, one in [`java.util.Base64`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) that debuted in Java 8, and some methods in [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) that have been around since at least Java 6. There are also other classes out there, such as the iHarder base64 class which has [a nice page](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) describing it and other base64 decoders, and the base64 decoder in [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Note that some of the libraries provided above do not throw an exception when decoding invalid Base64 characters either. This was something I discovered by experimenting with different Base64 libraries. Eventually, I solved the problem by explicitly checking to see if my bit-flip produced a Base64 character. If it didn't, I undid the bit flip and picked a new bit to flip.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "no".

Any bytestream B has exactly one base64 encoding E.  The encoded stream E is the only valid bytestream which decodes to bytestream B.  That's just the way B64 works.

What happened in your example is you changed a character in your string to something invalid in standard base64.  How the decoder deals with that is going to be implementation-specific.