# Converting from Base64 returns the same result for different strings

Tags: c#, base64, decoding

Why do this two lines of code deliver the same result? (The third character is different)

```
Convert.FromBase64String("aaa=") 
Convert.FromBase64String("aab=")
```

Result is the same for both lines - hex - [0x69, a6] / decimal [105, 166]

Other tests delivered those *insights*:

- converting back gives yet another different string -  `aaY=` : `Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromBase64String("aaa="))`
- "aac=" is different [105,**167**]
- "aaaa" and "aaab" are decoded to different sequences

Why is do I get the same results in the first examples? What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you print the data? do you overwrite the same variable?

Comment: Each Base64 character encodes 6 bit. You have 3*6= 18bits, which are decoded to 2 bytes and the remaining 2 bits get thrown away. But `a` and `b` just differ in the last bit, so the difference is in the part that gets cut off.

Comment: Encoding of something as base64 shouldn't get you to the bytes you have for decoding here. Maybe make the complete roundtrip when evaluating base64. Encoding and decoding.

Comment: We should have language-agnostic duplicate... but we don't. And we don't close cross-language for *reasons* - same covered in Java version - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941270/why-do-base64-decode-produce-same-byte-array-for-different-strings.

Comment: abc, I've edited post to replace byte arrays with strings as I think it is easier to read. Feel free to [edit] or rollback if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

base-64 is 6 bits of data per character; 3 characters gives you 18 bits, but for two bytes you only need 16. That leaves 2 bits of noise. Any changes in that noise: will not matter. The change you're seeing is only in the noise bits.